# How to properly auto-start APP

Tags: android, service, boot, autostart

i'm having trouble with the auto-start feature of my APP.

I've searched trhough the forums, seen many suggestions, none seems to work and I don't know why.

Here's the **BootUpReciver.java**

```
package com.???.???;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootUpReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        //Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
        //context.startService(pushIntent);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Device Booted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("TAG","Device Booted");

    }
}
}
```

And here's my **Manifest** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.???.???"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <receiver android:name=".BootUpReciver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.???.???.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When i restart my phone i don't even see the Toast, why? what should i do? I need to auto-start to get some sharedprefs and write a value to a file every boot.

Thanks.

Comment: debug and see if the onreceive is called after boot

Comment: StinePike, how can i do that? i mean, is it even possible to be debugging after a reboot? o_o or to look at a LogCat events?

Comment: let me check .. so wait if you can

Answer (score 0):

While testing I found that If I show toast in onReceive then it is not showing. But if I start an activity in onReceive then it is working. So you can also check this. Start an activity or service and perform your task there.